# CoreData crash after returning from background

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app, I have this one CoreData context that I approach in all my view controllers as follows:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

In a specific detail view controller, I do the following:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        do {
            myCoredataObject.attribute = aTextView.text
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Now, I can move back and forth between the master view controller and this detail view controller and make changes to the object. The changes seem to persist: after relaunching the app from Xcode, myCoredataObject.attribute has the same value as before the relaunch.

However, when I switch to another app, revisit my app, and make changes to myCoredataObject.attribute, the `try context.save()` crashes with a

> Fatal error: Failure to save context: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=133020

For the sake of it, I have put another `try context.save()` in my applicationDidEnterBackground, but to no avail.

I guess it has something to do with threading. Could any of you advise me on how to solve this?

Comment: https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=133020 it seems like you are modifying the record in more than one location and the default merge policy is to generate an error. You can either identify why you have a merge conflict, change the merge policy on your context or change the fatal error to a soft error and continue.

Comment: thanks! I added 
context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
to my exit method, and errors stopped

Comment: The merge policy is just hiding other issues in your code...There should never be any merge issues when you have a single context in use. ie Don't access your persistentContainer via the AppDelegate singleton. Use dependency injection to pass the context into your ViewController, now you know you are always dealing with the same context - no merge issues.